# Golang sql - how to handle Procedure OUT params

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, go

I have an oracle procedure, which i call like that:

```
DECLARE
  ID       NUMBER := 12345;
  Var1     NUMBER := NULL;
  Var2     NUMBER := NULL;
BEGIN
  PKG_A.GET_ACCOUNT_VALUES(
    ACCOUNT_ID     => ID,
    SOMEVALUE1     => Var1,
    SOMEVALUE2     => Var2
  );
END;
```

ID param is IN/OUT, Var1 and Var2 - OUT.

It's an external system, I can`t change this procedure.
How can I get this three values with the help of database/sql library (oci8 driver)?
Can I bind somehow, to this Params, or maybe get them with DBMS_OUTPUT some way.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What SQL type is being returned to Go?  (I know the answer.) How do you handle this type in Go?  What type does `Select 1,2,3;` return?

Comment: Well, it doesn`t matter in this case. Let it be sql.NullInt64. But I can replace NUBER with VARCHAR2, and use string in Go. I`m just intereting - how can I bind go variables to oracle variables.

Comment: The SQL type returned is a RECORD. How would you bind to the returned record of `SELECT 'a', 3 LIMIT 1;`?